# How to simulate Nash equilibria

Tags: algorithm

I have a N person game where each person has a set of M discrete strategies. I know from the theory that at least one mixed strategy Nash Equilibrium exists.

Can someone please tell me how do I find one of those equilibrium points by numerical simulation?

I can not find in the book any explanation of how to simulate. I just need the basic direction.

I asked this question in math.stackexchange but decided to ask here as well in case this is the correct place for algorithms.

Thank you.

Comment: You may have more luck on math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Chris I don't know where I should post this question. I still didn't get an answer there. Thank you

Comment: If you're looking for code on how to write it, this isn't the correct place. You clearly don't understand the theory behind it, which is why you should go to Math.stackexchange first. Then come back here when you have issues with the *implementation* of it.

Comment: [this handout](https://files.nyu.edu/caw1/public/MAGame/Handouts/mgas13s01comuputingne.pdf) may be of interest.

Comment: @collapsar Thank you. But that note is for 2 person games. I have a general N person game and in my simulation N has to be at least 10. For two person game they already have a standard algorithm Lemke–Howson.

Comment: [this paper](http://works.bepress.com/wilson_robert/8) claims to provide a scheme for computing n-player game equilibria to an arbitrary precision and [this one](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165188903001088)  (full text behind a paywall) takes another approach.

Comment: [You shouldn't cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Flag the question for migration or, before asking the question on another site, delete the other one. Though I believe this is off topic for [so], I'm not sure where it belongs.

Comment: Please migrate this question to Math.SE

Comment: @Jacob Thank you. I got better answers from this site than Math.se. So may be this community knows about this problem better since it is about algorithms. I am not asking for code. Is there a way to know which community is best for a question without cross posting?

Comment: @MLT: SO is stellar at coding. It's performance with algorithms is alright for questions at the graduate CS level (not research questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of the game you have, in some case it is not possible and in other (2xN zero-sum games, potential game) it can be costly.

If the game has a pure Nash Equilibrium then the Fictitious play algorithm of Brown then then improved by Berger can find it [G. W. Brown, Iterative solution of games by fictitious play, MIT Press, 1998 and Berger, Brown's original fictitious play, Journal of Economic Theory, 2007]. A stichastic version of it has been proposed by Smyrnakis & Leslie [Michail Smyrnakis et David Leslie, Stochastic Fictitious Play using Particle Filters to update the beliefs of opponents strategies, 2008]. You can browse the wikipedia page at first : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_play.

If you are looking for a mixed NE it is even more tricky and some learning algorithm can be quite bad while others are better. I personnally like the book of Cesa-Bianchi and Lugosi, Prediction, Learning and Games, http://homes.di.unimi.it/~cesabian/predbook/. Other people like also Nisan's Algorithmic Game Theory.